# React list component (like filemanager)

Tags: reactjs

Help me, please.  Which is a good open-source React component for creation list with sorting and folders similar to filemanager?
Like on this screenshot:
https://prnt.sc/yj5rj2

Or maybe, it is easier to write own component? Many datagrid components are too tricky.

Comment: I think you can use simple table here with some css. e.g https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_intro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try Material UI Tree View: https://material-ui.com/components/tree-view/. Take a look at the Gmail clone sample.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I looked at the documentation of Material UI Tree View.
I can't solve three questions.

1. Does it have sorting?

2. Can additional columns be added to the tree, for example filesize, date, etc ?

3. Is it possible to use my own styles and icons? I use Bootstrap framework, it has another assets. If I import many '@material-ui/...' resources line in the examples, it will be heavy and awkward.

Comment: I see. If you are using BS then don't bother with MUI. Shouldn't use 2 styling libraries in one project. Better off write your own filemanager with BS.